# .Net C# + Autofac + Azure KeyVault SecretClient: 'ContainerBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddSecretClient'

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control, autofac

I'm using IoC with Autofac to register dependencies in my project, but I'm not being able to register a SecretClient.

AutofacConfigurationExtensions:

```
public static class AutofacConfigurationExtensions
{
    public static void AddAutofac(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory());

        builder.ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>
        (
            (_, builder) =>
            {
                builder.RegisterAssemblyModules(typeof(AutofacConfigurationExtensions));
                builder.RegisterModule(new SharedAutofacModule());
            }
        );
    }
}
```

SharedAutofacModule:

```
using Autofac;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Azure;

public class SharedAutofacModule : Autofac.Module
{
    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var uri = new Uri("keyVaultUrl");
        var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = "clientId" });

        //attempt 1
        builder.AddSecretClient<SecretClient>(uri).WithCredential(tokenCredential);
        //attempt 2
        builder.AddSecretClient<SecretClient>(_ => new(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), tokenCredential));
        //attempt 3
        builder.RegisterType<SecretClient>(_ => new(new Uri("keyVaultUrl"), "tokenCredential"));

        builder.RegisterType<MicrosoftGraphEmailService>().As<IMailMessageSender>();
        builder.RegisterType<AzureKeyVaultSecretManager>();
    }
}
```

In my SharedAutofacModule I'm being able to register MicrosoftGraphEmailService and AzureKeyVaultSecretManager with no problem, but none of my 3 attempts on registering SecretClient do work, they just won't build. The first 2 with the following error:

> 'ContainerBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'AddSecretClient'
> and the best extension method overload
> 'SecretClientBuilderExtensions.AddSecretClient(SecretClient,
> Uri)' requires a receiver of type 'SecretClient'

And the third it gives the following error:

> No overload for method 'RegisterType' takes 1 arguments

If I use DI in the traditional Microsoft's way (like in the following piece of code) registration of SecretClient works with no problem, but I need to do it with Autofac.

Program.cs:

```
var config = InitConfiguration();
var clientId = config["AzureKeyVault:ClientId"];
var keyVaultUrl = config["AzureKeyVault:KeyVaultUrl"];

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(clientId) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(keyVaultUrl))
{
    var tokenCredential = new DefaultAzureCredential(new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions { ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId });

    var builder = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureFunctionsWorkerDefaults()
    .ConfigureServices(s => s.AddSingleton<SecretClient>(_ => new(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), tokenCredential)));

    builder.AddAutofac();
    var host = builder.Build();
    await host.RunAsync();
}
```

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example using [EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac) nuget package.

I created a new ASP.NET Core app: `AzureKeyVaultSecretClientExample`

**AzureKeyVaultSecretClientExample.csproj**

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection" Version="8.0.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Identity" Version="1.8.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets" Version="4.4.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac" Version="2.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**Program.cs**

```cs
using System;

using Autofac;
using Autofac.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.Security.KeyVault.Secrets;

using EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder
    .Host
    .UseServiceProviderFactory(new AutofacServiceProviderFactory())
    .ConfigureContainer<ContainerBuilder>(
        (hostBuilderContext, containerBuilder) =>
        {
            containerBuilder
                // Discover all assemblies starting with the specified names.
                .UseDefaultAssemblyRegistry(
                    nameof(AzureKeyVaultSecretClientExample),
                    nameof(EgonsoftHU)
                )
                // Enables injection for Autofac modules.
                .TreatModulesAsServices()
                // It will inject the IConfiguration instance
                // into Autofac modules using property injection.
                .RegisterModuleDependencyInstance(
                    hostBuilderContext.Configuration
                )
                // Register the EgonsoftHU Autofac module
                // that will discover and register
                // all other Autofac modules.
                .RegisterModule<DependencyModule>();
        }
    );

// Add services to the container.
builder
    .Services
    .AddControllers()
    .AddControllersAsServices();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllers();
app.Run();

public class AzureDependencyModule : Module
{
    // It will be automatically injected.
    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; } = default!;

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        var clientId = Configuration["AzureKeyVault:ClientId"];
        var keyVaultUrl = Configuration["AzureKeyVault:KeyVaultUrl"];

        var tokenCredential =
            new DefaultAzureCredential(
                new DefaultAzureCredentialOptions()
                {
                    ManagedIdentityClientId = clientId
                }
            );

        // Register a factory delegate.
        builder.Register<SecretClient>(
            context =>
            new(new Uri(keyVaultUrl), tokenCredential)
        );
    }
}
```

**Please note:** The `.RegisterModuleDependencyInstance<T>(T instance)` method uses a temporary, separate Autofac container exclusively for the Autofac modules.

Learn more [here](https://github.com/gcsizmadia/EgonsoftHU.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Autofac) about this nuget package.